# Software allowing graphical polynomial interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation, math-software, mathematica

**Hey!**

I'm sorry because this is NOT I highly professional mathematic question, but I thought that it would be misplaced in the software engineering community.

I'm looking for a tool allowing me to do something like placing points in a 2-dimensional coordinate system and polynomial interpolating a line between those points.

Does anybody know if something like this can be realized with Matlab or Wolfram's Mathematica

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html),
 [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)

Comment: If you want to do **interactive** visual interpolation, **clicking** into a canvas, you can do that with both tools. But is this all you want to do? Other features pull apart these tools and are much more relevant to make an informed choice. Anyway, for _MATLAB_ you could look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35056-interactive-curve-class) and for _Mathematica_ at [that](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SmoothlyInterpolatingASetOfData). I think this question should be moved to the main [so].